# Convergence of power series.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R.$ Now can i say that there is at least one point on the circle of convergence $|z|=R$ at which the power series will not converge? I am thinking so because if the power series is convergent at all points of the the circle of convergence then $f$ will be analytic at $|z|=R$ and radius of convergence will increase and which is not possible. Am i right? Please suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can consider $a_n=1/n^2$. The power series has radius of convergence 1 but it converges at all points of the boundary of unit circle.

Comment: So does $\sum z^n/n^2$ not have a pole within $|z|\leq 1$? What is the pole structure of this function?

Comment: According to [this wolfram page](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/04/03/), [dilogarithm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462634/short-calculation-of-the-dilogarithm) does not have any poles. But I'm confused. Isn't a meromorphic function analytic in any domain where it does not have any poles? Shouldn't this make the dilogarithm anaylitic on $\mathbb{C}$ and therefore its Taylor series converges on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391707/singularity-of-analytic-continuation-of-fz-sum-n-1-infty-fracznn2/391716) seems to contain an answer to my question, but I didn't quite understand it. Maybe I should start a new question.