# Confusion regarding analytic extension of series.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I am worinkg with the complex function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{3^n}$ . How can I prove that the function cannot be analytically continued past the unit circle.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: show that the series is infinite at all roots of unity of order various powers of three and show that those are dense in the unit circle; conclude

Comment: $f(z)=z+f(z^{3})$. Use the argument in the following link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264413/analytic-continuation-of-a-power-series-2?rq=1

Comment: I´ll try the argument! Thanks.